# What is the state of the art in internet timing attacks?

Tags: timing-attack

What is the shortest timing difference resolved by a timing attack demonstrated over the internet (not just a LAN)?

[This paper](http://statistics.rice.edu/uploadedFiles/Technical_Reports/RiediTR2007-06-BitLeak.pdf) from 2009 suggests 15µs. By how much has that number improved?

Comment: I think the question should be limited to **B-Tree index in PostgreSQL** as extending it makes a cumulative answer almost impossible.

Comment: The only difference between remote and local timing attacks is the jitter that network devices introduce.  Gig Ethernet vs MPLS vs DS3 may have a hand in reducing jitter and increasing the chance of a timing attack.

Comment: The question has been narrowed. Can it be reopened?